# keep only those columns in the first file which their column numbers match to numbers in the second file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a *genotype.file* with 317 columns (1, 2, 3, ..., 317). 
In the example below I am just showing the first few columns!

Input `genotype.file`:

```
Chr00c0002  56240   N   N   N   A   N   A   N   N   N   N   N   A   
Chr00c0040  55087   N   N   N   C   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   
Chr00c0041  24730   N   N   N   A   N   A   N   N   N   N   N   N   
...
```

I want to keep only those columns that match to each of my `count.files`. This is one of my count files and I have in total 50 count file (count.file.1, count.file.2, ..., count.file.50)!

```
cat count.file.1
51
92
166
169
196
199
213
228
229
284
291
297
```

So for the first *count.file* I want to keep only columns 51, 92, 166, 169, ... from the *genotype.file*.

Comment: Oh no, I just showed the first few columns of genotype file here, the real one has 317 columns. I edited slightly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `genotype.file` file is tab-delimited:

```
cut -f $(tr '\n' ',' <count.file.1 | sed 's/,$//') genotype.file
```

The command substitution, `$( tr ... | sed ... )`, generates a comma-delimited list of column numbers for `cut` to cut from the input file.

The `tr` replaces all newlines by commas in the `count.file.1` file, while `sed` removes the extra comma at the end.

The resulting command will look like the following, given the example data:

```
cut -f 51,92,166,169,196,199,213,228,229,284,291,297 genotype.file
```

To loop over your `count.file.*` files:

```
for cfile in count.file.*; do
    cut -f $(tr '\n' ',' <"$cfile" | sed 's/,$//') genotype.file >genotype-"${cfile##*.}"
done
```

This creates new file called `genotype-N` where `N` is the number corresponding to the `count.file.N` that was used to generate it from `genotype.file`.  The number is extracted from the end of the filename.

---

If `genotype.file` is *not* tab-delimited, you may make it tab-delimited:

```
tr -s ' ' '\t' <genotype.file >genotype.tsv
```

This assumes that the columns in the original file are separated by only spaces.  The `tr` command will replace multiple consecutive spaces with a tab.  The result is redirected to a new file. You would use the `cut` command above on this new file.

---

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR { c[++n] = $0; next } { t=$c[1]; for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) t = t OFS $c[i]; print t }' count.file.1 genotype.file
```

This will first read `count.file.1` to get the columns that we'd like to extract from `genotype.file` into the array `c`, and then, when we read `genotype.file`, those column numbers are used to extract the data.  `t` is a temporary variable that holds the output line constructed from the selected columns.

To loop over your `count.file.*` files:

```
for cfile in count.file.*; do
    awk 'NR == FNR { c[++n] = $0; next } { t=$c[1]; for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) t = t OFS $c[i]; print t }' \
        "$cfile" genotype.file >genotype-"${cfile##*.}"
done
```

This creates new file called `genotype-N` in the same manner as with the `cut` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` only with simple script.

```bsh
awk '{ printf "{ print ";for(i=1; i<NF; i++){ printf "$%d, ",$i};
       print "$"$i" }" }' <<< "$(awk '{printf $0" "}' count.file.{1..50})" >genotype.awk
```

This will produces an `awk` script called `genotype.awk` like below, which will collect all column-numbers are in all `count.file.{1..50}` files. We used [`Brace Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) here to read all those 50 files by `awk`.

```
{ print $51, $92, $166, $169, $196, $199, $213, $228, $229, $284, $291, $297, ... }
```

**Usage:**

```
awk -f genotype.awk genotype.file
```

This will perform executing `genotype.awk` script on `genotype.file` file and will print included columns-number only.